# Cannot printout concatenated tensor by tf.concat() (tensorflow 1.2.1 - gpu / py36)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

Learning **[Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/)** (Python bindings) since the last month. I've been reading the docs on `tf.concat()`, but cannot resolve the problem as shown below, so I'm asking for your help!

What I want to do is to see the contents of the concatenated tensor.
I tried `Tensor.eval()`.

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np 

a=np.zeros([3,3])
a_trail=np.ones([3,3])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    concatenated=tf.concat([a, a_trail], axis=0) 
    print(concatenated)
    print(type(concatenated)) 
    concatenated.eval() 
    sess.run(concatenated) 
    sess.run(tf.constant(concatenated))
```

**Output:**

```
Tensor("concat_2:0", shape=(6, 3), dtype=float64)
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
(nothing prints)
(nothing shows up either meh =/)
Error: List of Tensors when single Tensor expected
```

`tf.concat()` supposed to return `Tensor` and looks like it does. But why aren't `T.eval()` and `sess.run()` not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of TF functions take tensors as parameters. This applies to [tf.concat](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat). As you can see from the documentation:

> values: A list of Tensor objects or a single Tensor.

And you provide numpy arrays and not tensors. Here is a working example.

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np 

a=np.zeros([3,3])
b=np.ones([3,3])

A = tf.constant(a)
B = tf.constant(b)
concatenated=tf.concat([A, B], axis=0) 

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print sess.run(concatenated)
```

Not related to your question, but separate a graph definition from a graph execution (you do everything in `tf.session`, I define everything outside and only execute in the session

Comment: thx. not exactly the same with what you've done here but I tried going straight <code>tf.concat()</code> with both np.ndarray and placeholders. And it looked like putting just np.ndarray as an input seemed work, I did this.

Comment: So...you recommend converting them into <code>Tensor</code> before concatenating the two above is that right? @Salvador Dali